# How to enable log rotation of supervisor in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm

IS that any configuration file that can let me enable the log rotation of supervisor in Storm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean the `supervisor.log` file right?

for 0.9.x version of storm, you can edit logback/cluster.xml, and for 0.10.x version, log4j2/cluster.xml files as you wish your logger to behave, including log rotation.